# Uploading Files (PDF & Image) With CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

What I am trying to do I have never done before. I am using CakePHP to build a form, I am using the form helper to do this. This all works with inputs and textareas but I am now trying to changed two of my inputs into file upload fields.

This I have done and seems the work, when I debug $this->data['Event']['img'] (The form is call Event). I get the following output :

```
Array
 (
   [name] => logo.gif
   [type] => image/gif
   [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpaU3aBa
   [error] => 0
   [size] => 7318
 )
```

Now I am guesting here but I would have to save the file to my 'webroot' folder. I have made the path /webroot/eventfiles/img & webroot/eventfiles/pdf - I have started with doing just the image for now, so I can get it to work, but the other file type I will be uploading is a pdf.

Now I have looked at what the CakePHP website as on this but I just says to look at the PHP site and there seems to be a lot of ways to do this, but I am just not sure how to save it. So that I can access it later, e.g. it goes into the webroot folder so that Cake can see it.

Also as a side note, would also need to save the path + filename into the database. This, unless I am wrong, should be easy, just use $this->data['Event']['img']['name'] and that would save that into my database.

Please help? I have been working on this for days. I just can not seem to get my head around file upload. Is there a easy method to do this? E.g like how Cake as HTML & Form helpers, a easy method for saving uploaded files?

Thanks For Any Help You Can Give.

Glenn.

Comment: I do know a lot of people say that you should search this site before posting and in my defence I did that, there are just so many posts about file uploading and the ones I did try didn't work! But this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872364/how-to-save-image-in-cakephp?rq=1 - with a little editing did!

Answer (score 0):

just though that I would post my answer, which fully works. I takes a pdf and jpeg image, from two file input files and then renames then to the given title, supplied by the user in a input text field. With the two vars in $newevent, these are what, with the other inputs, are saved to the database, path and the renamed image.

This code is very simple. The main body of this code come from a post on this site and I have just changed it to use for my use.

If you are also trying to add/upload different file types, e.g. doc or png, all you need to know is the header type for the document you want to upload and add it to the if statement.

Hope this will help someone else!

Glenn.

```
            $pathimg = "/eventfiles/img/";
            $pathpdf = "/eventfiles/pdf/";
            $dir_pdf = getcwd().$pathpdf;
            $dir_img = getcwd().$pathimg;
            $PDF_Path = $dir_pdf .  $this->data['Event']['pdf']["name"];
            $IMG_Path = $dir_img .  $this->data['Event']['img']["name"];
            $IMG_WithOutSpace = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $newevent['title']);
            $PDF_WithOutSpace = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $newevent['title']);

            $newevent['img'] = "/vh/eventfiles/img/" . $IMG_WithOutSpace . ".jpg";
            $newevent['pdf'] = "/vh/eventfiles/pdf/" . $PDF_WithOutSpace . ".pdf";

        if ((( $this->data['Event']['img']["type"] == "application/pdf") || ( $this->data['Event']['img']["type"] == "image/jpeg"))) {
          if (($this->data['Event']['img']["error"] > 0) || ($this->data['Event']['pdf']["error"] > 0)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('An error has occured during updating. Please check all the fields.', true), 'default', array('class' => 'error-message'));
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
            exit();
          } else {

              move_uploaded_file( $this->data['Event']['img']["tmp_name"], $IMG_Path);
              rename($IMG_Path, $dir_img . $IMG_WithOutSpace. ".jpg");

              move_uploaded_file( $this->data['Event']['pdf']["tmp_name"], $PDF_Path);
              rename($PDF_Path, $dir_pdf . $PDF_WithOutSpace . ".pdf");

              $filename= $this->data['Event']['pdf']["name"];
              $filename= $this->data['Event']['img']["name"];
          }
```

Comment: Please just note that this is built to work inside CakePHP so there may be functions that might not work inside PHP without the Cake framework.